# Difficulty Redirecting to a 404 Page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to redirect to a 404 page if the user profile visited does not exist. I'm running an asynchronous created lifecycle hook which checks if the user exists, and if not I use `$router.push` to push to the 404 page, as shown below:

`component.vue`

```
async created() {
    const userExists = await this.$store.dispatch("user/creatorExists", {
        userId: this.$route.params.userId
    });
    if (!userExists) {
        this.$router.push({ name: "pageNotFound" });
    }
```

The problem is that during the call to check if the user exists or not, `component.vue` will load fully, so the end user will see the initial component flicker on their screen before being redirected.

Is there a better way to redirect to a 404 page if a user does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `beforeRouteEnter` [in-component navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

```js
import store from "wherever/your/store/lives"

export default {
  name: "UserProfile",
  async beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    const userExists = await store.dispatch("user/creatorExists", {
        userId: to.params.userId
    });
    if (!userExists) {
        return next({ name: "pageNotFound" });
    }
    next()
  },
  // data, computed, methods, etc
}
```

See also [Data Fetching - Fetching Before Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation)

Note that there is no access to the Vue component via `this` within the `beforeRouteEnter` guard so you'll need to import your `store` from wherever it is defined.

Comment: Thank you. What's the advantage of this over router.beforeEach?

Comment: @Matt the global navigation guards execute for every route change, no matter what route. They are a good spot for global logic (like authentication checks) but I thought your use-case above was very specific to this particular component

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you should put logic in the [global before guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) using `router.beforeEach`

```js
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 // Check each time before entering the page or a specific page  
})
```